# How to plot estimated CDF with empirical CDF

Tags: r, ecdf

I am fitting a distribution to a given data.then I have estimated parameters of the distribution.I have also plotted the empirical cdf using ecdf() command in R. Now I have to plot cdf of estimated distribution along with empirical cdf. How I can do it? Can the ecdf() command still help me?

Comment: Thanx dear, let me ask my question more specifically
I have estimated parameters of "loglogistic distribution" I want to compare cdf of loglogistic distribution with emperical cdf how can i compare it visually.I have plottd the empirical cdf using ecdf().the plotting of LL cdf remains.

Comment: This is a coding site. Post code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ecdf`can help you. It has a plotting method. Below you see possible code for a normal distribution.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(ecdf(x))
lines(seq(-3, 3, by=.1), pnorm(seq(-3, 3, by=.1)), col=2)
```

EDIT: You can do the same thing using the log-logistic distribution function instead. It is implemented for instance in package `actuar`.

```
# load package
require(actuar)
# check out the parametrization! 
?dllogis
# estimate shape and scale from your data
shape <- 20
scale <- 1
# Don't do this. Use your own data instead. 
x <- rllogis(100, shape=shape, scale=scale)
# Plotting the empirical distribution function
plot(ecdf(x))
# x-values for plotting distribution function
xvals <- seq(min(x), max(x), length=100)
# plot estimated distribution function with your estimated shape and scale
lines(xvals, pllogis(xvals, shape=shape, scale=scale), col=2)
```

Comment: Thanx dear, let me ask my question more specifically
I have estimated parameters of "loglogistic distribution" I want to compare cdf of loglogistic distribution with emperical cdf how can i compare it visually.I have plottd the empirical cdf using ecdf().the plotting of LL cdf remains.